# ngnix не отдает статику (docker compose + gunicorn + flask)

Tags: nginx, docker, flask, docker-compose, gunicorn

Добрый вечер. Имею следующий `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '2'
services:

  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '443:443'
    volumes:
      - ./src/app/static:/flask-app/src/app/static
      - ./conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
      - ./logs/nginx_access.log:/var/log/nginx_access.log
      - ./logs/nginx_error.log:/var/log/nginx_error.log
    depends_on:
      - web

  web:
    build: ./
    command: gunicorn manage:app --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --access-logfile=logs/gunicorn_access_log.txt
    ports:
    - '8000:8000'
    volumes:
    - ./:/flask-app
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: postgresql://postgres:pass@localhost/flask_deploy
      REDIS_HOST: redis
      SECRET_KEY: 'BbGd3qe$dsf1'
      CONFIG_NAME: 'prod'
    links:
      - postgres:postgres
      - redis:redis
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis

  postgres:
    image: postgres:9.4
    volumes:
      - ./psql-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 'pass'
      POSTGRES_DB: 'flask_deploy'
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'

  redis:
    image: "redis:3.0-alpine"
    command: redis-server
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'
```

`Dockerfile` для сборки контейнера с python (на всякий случай):

```
FROM python:3
#RUN apt-get install libpq-dev python-dev
RUN mkdir /flask-app
WORKDIR /flask-app
# Добавим файл с зависимостями в рабочий каталог контейнера
ADD requirements.txt /flask-app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
# Добавим содержимое папки src хоста в src папку контейнера
ADD . /flask-app
```

Конфиг `ngnix`:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    root /flask-app/src/app;

    # запись доступа и журналы ошибок в /var/log
    access_log /var/log/nginx_access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx_error.log;

    location / {
        # переадресация запросов приложений на сервер gunicorn
        proxy_pass http://web:8000;
    }

    location /static {
        # обрабатывать статические файлы напрямую, без пересылки в приложение
        autoindex on;
        expires 1d;
    }
}
```

Там, где в конфиге ngnix фигурирует `web` - это тот `web`, что описан в `docker-compose.yml`

Приложение функционирует как нужно, за одним исключением - ссылки на статику выглядят так:

```
http://web:8000/static/img/do.jpg
```

Данная ссылка будет битой, изображения не будет. Можно исправить на:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/img/do.jpg
```

Тогда ссылка откроется и картинка будет, но отдаст ее gunicorn. В чем беда? Я зеленый и в Docker, и в Ngnix, но хотелось бы разобраться. Услышать комментарии по конфигу тоже рад буду. Спасибо!

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста кто формирует данную ссылку `http://web:8000/static/img/do.jpg` и что произойдет если вы перейдете по адресу `http://127.0.0.1:80/static/img/do.jpg`

Comment: @Geslot я обновил вопрос, посмотрите, пожалуйста. Теперь осталась лишь одна проблема - генерация ссылки. Ссылку генерирует Flask (url_for()). Эта функция может генерировать относительную и полную ссылки. С относительной все ок, картинка показывается, а вот с полной - нет. У Фласка есть параметр - SERVER_NAME. Если его поменять на localhost - то будет ошибка not found

Comment: Вот Вы сказали если SERVER_NAME выставить в localhost, то получаете not found. А по какому адресу запрос идет в данном случае?

Comment: @Geslot не совсем Вас понял.. Запрос в таком случае идет на localhost, но почему-то минуя роуты. Получаю not founed, но, походу, от фласка все-таки

Comment: Меня интересовал полный адрес, с портом, потому что есть подозрение что у вас адрес формируется на порт 8000, а должен на 80, на котором развернут nginx.

Comment: @Geslot кажется, формируется на http://127.0.0.1/ . Без порта. При попытке ручками порт прописать - один и тот же результат и при 80 и при 8000 (нот фоунд)

Comment: @Geslot web:8000 железно стоит. залил на digital ocean попробовать - результат аналогично локальной машине

Comment: Убедитесь что у вас в вызов функции url_for передаётся параметр _external со значением True, должно выглядеть примерно так: `url_for("static", _external=True)`

Comment: @Geslot да, конечно, это я проверил несколько раз уже

Comment: @Geslot посмотрите, пожалуйста. Добавил решение, но теперь статику, кажется, отдает опять gunicorn..

Answer (score 0):

В конфиг nginx добавил:

```
proxy_set_header Host $host:8000;
```

Полный конфиг:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    root /flask-app/src/app;

    access_log /var/log/nginx_access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx_error.log;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host:8000;
        proxy_pass http://web:8000;
    }

    location /static {
        autoindex on;
        expires 1d;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

В конфиге `nginx` Вы указываете что слушаете 80 порт и ваша статика находится по адресу `/static`.
Для получения статики Вы должны обращаться  `http://ip_or_hostname/static/img/do.jpg`

- `ip_or_hostname` здесь ваш host ip или доменное имя.

Попробуйте через curl проверить запрос:
`curl -L http://ip_or_hostname/static/img/do.jpg`